# How do I set up automatic versioning when building npm (yarn)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I want to solve a long-standing problem in my project with caching by the javascript browser when building a yarn project written in vue.

I want a random salt to be added to the files during yarn build and an alert would be displayed to the user who is sitting on the site.

How do I add random salt through assembly? I can't find it. Regarding versioning, too, I have not yet come up with a better way to store versions on the client and on the server that would be checked, that is, each build assumes an increase in the version on the server and when you click on the update agreement, the version on the client would increase.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is solved primarily from server side. If a webserver caches everything including html page, that's it. Vue CLI hashes bundle files default. Since you said nothing on your setup, the answer is, it depends on your case.

Comment: @EstusFlask. Just vue-cli (From the finished assembly , it was created from scratch) bundle project and backend laravel. Simple setup

Comment: Vue cli should create hashed bundle files. See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#filenamehashing

Comment: @EstusFlask It turns out everything goes out of the box and you don't need to reset the cache with a reboot, but you can just reload the page? Ok. I would then like to do a soft page reload when building a new version. To alert the user that a new version has been released and reload the page (but do it gently). I'm thinking of storing the version on the server, is it a good idea?